# Собираем Jquery-велосипед по событию .click

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте, мои маленькие любители говнокода. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: жил-был ajax-запрос, который получал при помощи googleAPI коротенькие ссылочки, но затем Гудвину сказали прикрутить список, который должен методично заполняться по получению новой ссылки. Гудвин попробовал создать массив, в который заносятся .push элементы, но потом заметил, что список получается совсем не такой, какой он хотел. Внимание, знатоки, вопрос: "А как бы вы сделали такой список?".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list1').hide();
  $('#list2').hide();
  $('#list3').hide();
  $('#pagg').hide();
  var arr = [];
  $('#loading-example-btn').click( function() {

    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    var appUrl = $('#appendUrl').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=...",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        longUrl: appUrl
      }),
      error: function(err){
        // console.log('Error', err.statusText);
        $('#result').val(err.statusText);
      }
    }).done(function(result){
      // console.log('short URL:', result.id);
      $('#result').val(result.id);
      $('#lol').html('Ваша ссылка');
      var result = result.id;
      arr.push(result);
      var new_ul = '<ul class="list-group" id="linklist">'     
      for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { 
        new_ul += '<li class="list-group-item">'+arr[i]+'</li>';
        new_ul += '</ul>';
        $('#list1').replaceWith(new_ul);
        $('#list1').show();
        console.log(arr[i])      
      }
    }).always( function () {
      btn.button('reset');
    });
  })

});
```

**Обновление**

Собственно получился список из одной ссылки, которая потом не меняется, хоть массив и расширяется. Гудвин также пробовал сделать это через .append, то есть: `$('#list1').append(...+arr[i]+...)`, но список заполнялся следующим образом: вставляется 1-й элемент, затем вставляется 1 и 2, затем 1, 2, 3, и Гудвин получает список из повторяющихся элементов.

Гудвин будет очень презнателен, если ему кто-нибудь подскажет как проверить эл-ты массива на уникальность, т.е. если у нас есть уже этот эл-т в списке, он не попадал туда повторно.

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
```

Видать, в область видимости не попадает массив unique.

Comment: > список получается совсем не такой, какой он хотел

А какой список Гудвин хотел и какой получил?

Answer (score 1):

Создам ответ, потому что у вас, возможно, лимит комментариев под вопросом исчерпан. Создает новый массив из элементов переданного, в который попадают только уникальные элементы

```
var getUnique = function (arr) {
  var i = 0,
  current,
  length = arr.length,
  unique = [];
  for (; i < length; i++) {
    current = arr[i];
    if (!~unique.indexOf(current)) {
      unique.push(current);
    }
  }
  return unique;
};
```

Функция getUnique [работает нормально](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/pmuz0h0q/). Что у вас не попадает и зачем тут замыкание? Вы вообще в функцию getUnique передавали массив?

Comment: да, только вместо arr я указал unique в первой строчке. но все равно создается список из 1го, 1го и 2го, 1,2 и 3 и т.д. элементов.

Comment: Покажи на jsfiddle, как ты используешь функцию getUnique. Она строго принимает массив `arr` и возвращает массив уникальных элементов из `arr`. Если такое поведение не устраивает, то ее надо переписывать.